# Upload files to dynamic folders using random string in models.Filefield 'upload_to' entry

Tags: django

I am using `models.Filefield` to upload files to the server. When uploading a new file with name of an existing file, django append name with some random characters. But I need to retain filename. Hence I change `upload_to` entry in the `models.Filefield` to `upload_to='str(uuid.uuid4())'`. It works fine, but seldom the above problem occur. Is there any other methods to correct it ?

Comment: So basically, you want to overwrite existing files?

Comment: @GwynBleidD: I dont want to overwrite. But create a folder with random name and place file inside it.